# MySQL query does not work on SQLite

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have problem with one of my query in SQLite.
I'm writting an simple chat in java for android.

I get data from database on my server and inserting them to local database on device.
I want to get last message with each user.

When I get data from MySQL it's correct but when executing the same query (I copied it) on SQLite I get one more row. Is there different in code implementation between MySQL and SQLite?

```
SELECT _id, od, do, tresc, godzina
            FROM wiadomosci w
            WHERE
            (od = "Aaaa" AND _id =
            (SELECT max(_id) FROM wiadomosci
            WHERE (od = "Aaaa" AND do = w.do) OR (do = "Aaaa" AND od = w.do)))
            OR
            (do = "Aaaa" AND _id = (
            SELECT max(_id) FROM wiadomosci
            WHERE (do = "Aaaa" AND od = w.od) OR (od = "Aaaa" AND do = w.od)))
```

where:

- od - from whom the message is,
- do - to whom the message is,
- tresc - content of message,
- godzina - hour of message was sent

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This query relies on the `_id` column being autoincrementing. Is it? Even when you copy the records from the server?

Comment: Yes, _id is integer primary key (in SQLite it's autoincrement). Ids are the same on MySQL and on SQLite. When I get rows from server, id is also inserted into sqlite

Comment: Show some example rows and the actual/desired results.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a few quirks, including the fact that it accepts double quotes (`"`) for strings. This is not standard, as double quotes are normally for column names.

If you change your double quotes to single quotes you might have more success:

```
SELECT
    _id, od, do, tresc, godzina
FROM wiadomosci w
WHERE
(od = 'Aaaa' AND _id = (
    SELECT max(_id) FROM wiadomosci
            WHERE (od = 'Aaaa' AND do = w.do) OR (do = 'Aaaa' AND od = w.do)))
            OR
            (do = 'Aaaa' AND _id = (
            SELECT max(_id) FROM wiadomosci
            WHERE (do = 'Aaaa' AND od = w.od) OR (od = 'Aaaa' AND do = w.od)))
```